# Video not catching up with words. After upload on youtube

Tags: youtube, windows-movie-maker

I just uploaded a lyric video but it seems that Its lagging behind. Like for example. the song "ABC", It will play "ABCDE," then "FGHIJ" will allready be sung next but its still on the words "ABCDE" for a good 5 seconds before it moves on to "FGHIJ" of which of course the song would have allready moved on to "KLMNO". The problem is it plays perfectly on time in Windows Live Movie Maker. But when i uploaded it to youtube I get a laggy mess lol. I deleted the video twice. it is still deleted. I'm not putting it back up till i figure out how to fix it. I have 47 videos on my channel and never had any issues with them. So what gives?

UPDATE: I just realized its not catching up as well in Movie Maker but only when I rewind it back a little then play it, it plays correctly.. Since it played back correctly when I was first making it before upload I just thought that was just some sort of glitch and ignored it. And didn't think it would effect my video drastically...

Comment: Have you checked the video in VLC media player or another video player after export? Did the video have issues as well? It's unlikely that Youtube caused this error. What's more likely is your audio and video get out of sync over time because the audio uses another framerate than the video .. check that first.

Comment: Just to clear that up, of course audio doesn't have a framerate, but it's sample rate relates to the video's frame rate in a certain way that, if the software misinterprets it, can lead to video and audio being played back at slightly different speeds which can cause both to become out of sync. All of this is pretty complicated and I can't explain it well (tbh I have a hard time wrapping my head around it as well), however the bottom line is I've had this problem a long time ago when I tried WMM and it can be fixed by using editing software that doesn't suck (as opposed to Windows Movie Maker)